# Passing parameters from a subform to a query in MS Access Via. the OpenQuery Macro

Tags: sql, ms-access

What I am trying to do is to run a macro on a subform that will pass several values in text and check boxes to a parameter query I have written. I used a button and the event builder to use the `OpenQuery` Macro to run my query. My problem is I cannot get the syntax right in the "update parameters" section of the macro.

- The Main form is called "Main Navigation"
- The subform is "Procedure Balances by Date"
- The Controls are things like "ProfileBox" or "ProfileCheck"

I have tried many variations of the syntax. If I put the below into the macro, it ends up just asking me for the parameter instead.

```
[Forms]![Main Navigation]![NavigationSubform].[Form]![ProfileCheck]
```

I'm trying to idiot proof this thing, so I want the inputs to go through the various input masks I have on the textboxes, so It really is important that they come from the controls on the form. Also, I use this query in more than one place, so It has to be a parameter query. I cannot directly reference the form.

Please help! I cannot find the right syntax anywhere.

EDIT: Here is the Syntax of my Query:

```
PARAMETERS ProfCheck Bit, ProfBox Text (255), DateCheck Bit, StartDate DateTime, 
           EndDate DateTime, PracticeCheck Bit, 
           PracticeBox Text (255), ProcCheck Text (255), ProcBox Bit;

SELECT [Output Table].*
FROM [Output Table]
WHERE  (([ProfCheck] = 0 OR ( [ProfBox]=[profile] ) ) AND
          ([PracticeCheck] = 0 OR ( [PracticeBox]=[Practice Name] ) ) AND
          ([ProcCheck] = 0 OR ([Procedure Code] LIKE (([ProcBox])) ) ) AND
          ([DateCheck] = 0 OR ((([StartDate])<= [Date Svc From]) AND   
          (([EndDate]) >= [Date Svc From] ))));
```

I didn't think this was relevant, as I am just asking how to pass the parameters to it from the subform. The Query works fine once the parameters are there.

You are correct, *ProfileCheck* is a checkbox.

I am not using VBA. I am using the "OpenQuery" Macro built into Access.

Comment: Please post the full syntax of your query - it is difficult to assume where your reference is located, Also, I assume [ProfileCheck] is a 'checkbox'?  Also, what VBA code are you using to pass the parameters?

Comment: Parameters are quite restrictive. You need to enter exactly the right type of data. Try to wrap all parameters in your macro in an adequate casting function (`CBool` for the bits, `CStr` for the text fields, `CDate` for the dates)

Comment: I never use dynamic parameterized queries and definitely not with input popup. Build a form for user input. Query parameters reference form controls. Can better validate user input. Why open query instead of form or report bound to query? Even the casting can fail if user accidentally types alpha for a number or date type field.

Comment: Reread post again. I see you are trying to reference form controls - on a Navigation form. I don't like and have never used Navigation form because I find them frustrating. Also don't use macros, only VBA. I have never used PARAMETERS clause because I don't use dynamic parameterized queries. I prefer to set Filter property when opening form or report. Perhaps you should explore TempVars. And what do you mean by "cannot directly reference the form" - you must reference it at some point even to set parameters.

Comment: Did some testing with a Navigation form. No problem referencing the subform directly in the query. No PARAMETERS clause, no macro. Syntax with and without `.Form` worked.